# Firebase provider.ts Component auth has not been registered yet

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

I'm writing a very simple module to show how we can use Firebase. Here is the code:

```
import { initializeApp } from '/__/firebase/10.5.0/firebase-app.js';
import { getAuth } from '/__/firebase/10.5.0/firebase-auth.js';
import firebaseConfig from "./firebaseConfig.mjs";

function checkAuth() {
// Инициализируем Firebase
    console.debug("initializeApp()");
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

    if (!app) return null
    const auth = getAuth(app);

    return auth;
}

export { checkAuth }
```

The 'app' constant is successfully initialized, but the 'getAuth(app)' function throws an error:

```
Uncaught Error: Component auth has not been registered yet
    at Provider.initialize (provider.ts:239:13)
    at initializeAuth (emulator.ts:44:17)
    at getAuth (index.ts:82:5)
    at checkAuth (CheckAuth.mjs:11:18)
```

I've found a lot of discussion about this error but only from the Angular or other developer platforms point of view. But I just use a small local project from the Firebase documentation with local host and auth emulators.

I tried to reinstall firebase and firebase tools:

```
npm i firebase

npm i -g firebase-tools
```

Then I tried to re-init my project and have checked the right installation of the emulators.

Also I'm sure that the function `getAuth()` is called from the correct plase and have traced up to the *provider.ts* module.

Comment: I just found, that if I change the all local links prefixed by '/__/firebase/10.5.0/' to external ones prefixed by 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.5.0/' everything is working fine! But why???